# Retrieving input from Form Select - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I select a class from in my view and click on `Genrate`, I try to retrieve the value of the selected class but I am not able to get the value of the class selected.

When I return `$condition`, it returns empty. In the url after submitting, it shows like `http://localhost:8000/generate/timetable?class=`

Why is this happening?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-1">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="squareText">Type</label>
            {{ Form::select('class',$classes,$selectedClass,['class'=>'form-control','required'=>'true'])}}
            <br>
            <a href="/generate/timetable?class={{ request('class') }}"><button class="btn btn-primary pull-left square"  type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i> Generate</button></a>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$condition = Input::get('class');
if (!isset($condition['class']))
    $condition['class'] = 0;
$courses = $course->where('class',$condition)->get()->toArray();
return $condition;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is inside a link:

```
<a href="/generate/timetable?class={{ request('class') }}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left square" type="submit"> ... </button>
</a>
```

Clicking it is actually clicking the `<a href>` link, not clicking the button and submitting the form.  So instead of submitting the form, you are simply browsing to the URL the the link points to.

It isn't clear from your question what the link is there for, but if clicking the button is supposed to submit the form, you probably want to put your form elements inside an actual `<form>`.

It looks like you're using Laravel Collective (`{{ Form::select('class ....` looks like that), so see [those docs on how to open a form](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#opening-a-form):

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/generate/timetable?class=' . request('class')]) !!}
    {{ Form::select('class' .... }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left square" type="submit"> ... </button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

You'll probalby also need to add a CSRF token, it is also [described in the Laravel Collective docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#csrf-protection), as well as [in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf).